# ObjectMapper cannot properly deserialize json received as AMQP message body

Tags: java, spring-amqp, objectmapper

I created converter for deserializing messages to some custom message type.

This is the message I send in queue:
{
  "id":"851e04e5-356f-49a6-b6e2-93102dc7a642",
  "exportStatus": "EXPORTED"
}

This is the code of converter

```java
public class MergePatchAMQPMessageConverter implements MessageConverter {

    @Override
    public Message toMessage(Object o, MessageProperties messageProperties) throws MessageConversionException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public UpdateConfigurationCommand fromMessage(Message message) throws MessageConversionException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = null;
        try {
            jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(message.getBody());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO 
        }

        JsonNode id = jsonNode.get("id");
        if (id == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        JsonMergePatch patch = null;
        try (JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBody()))) {
            patch = Json.createMergePatch(reader.readValue());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MessageConversionException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return new UpdateConfigurationCommand(UUID.fromString(id.asText()), patch);
    }
}
```

When converter receives this message in message body ObjectMapper cannot deserialize it. The size of result JsonNode is 0. When I feet this message to ObjectMapper as regular String value it works properly.

What can be a reason?

Comment: Did you try debugging the code and see the actual content of the message body?

Comment: Yes, It looks like regular json